# Using ansible to automate machine rebuilds

Tags: windows, ansible

I'd like to use Ansible to rebuild the machines in my DC environment every X days as referred in the following article.

https://www.ansible.com/1000-windows-servers-on-a-30-day-rebuild

I understand that I can use Ansible to create playbooks to do things like install applications, but I can't find any examples on how to build / rebuild a host from scratch.

Can I use Ansible to do this and are there any examples I can follow?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a huge piece of work, which can't only be achieved with ansible only. As mentioned in this post they also use some sort of software deployment system which I think is crucial to achieve this kind of goal. Guess the setup of such a system which allows the installation of the OS would be the first step.

Comment: Regarding "_Can I use Ansible to do this_" the short answer might be yes, but without any information about what "_my DC environment_" means, it is probably impossible to answer. Whereby reading about certain use cases upfront is in general a good approach, "_I can't find any examples on how to build / rebuild a host from scratch_", there might be a lot. Do you have any specific questions or hints where you could experience problems?

Comment: You question need more context as the others underlined. That said, I would suggest you keep Ansible as a configuration manager tool and/or to do modification to an already existing machine. Therefore, using another tool to provision the VM. If it's cloud infrastructure, I would go TerraForm, CloudFormation or else.

Comment: This is far too broad and could be re-phrased as "deploy operating systems using Ansible". There is a reason solutions such as Ansible for Provisioning exists.  https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/provisioning-061618 . Additionally, most data center provisioning is done with hypervisor virtualization/templates, some people prefer to use WDS/WIMs.

Answer (score 0):

Building hosts themselves using ansible (as opposed to configuring already existing hosts) can be achieved using the [cloud modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html) available assuming that your "DC environment" is one of the supported clouds